With amsmidx, how do I cross reference without page numbers
I am using amsmidx because I have more than one index, although I don't need to if there is another way.  I have references such as
\documentclass[book]

...   
\Makeindex{name}
\Makeindex{subject}
\begin{document}
...............
\index{subject}{nonsense} blah  \index{subject}{gibberish|see{nonsense}}...................
\Printindex{subject}
\end{document}

What I get in the index is
gibberish, see also  nonsense
nonsense, 1
What I would like is
gibberish, see nonsense  (no italics and the word ``also'' deleted)
nonsense, 1

amsmidx was created to be used with AMS document classes.  It has flaws.  Since you're using the non-AMS book, multind might be a better choice.

Why not considering imakeidx?

imakeidx supports multiple indices and doesn't even require running MakeIndex separately.
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{imakeidx}

\makeindex[name=name,title=Index of names]
\makeindex[name=subject,title=Index of subjects]

\begin{document}

\index[name]{Gnu}
\index[name]{Gnat}

\index[subject]{nonsense} blah  
\index[subject]{gibberish|see{nonsense}}...................

\printindex[subject]
\printindex[name]

\end{document}




Sorry I didn't think of imakeidx.  It's the obvious approach.
